# Faster way to check connectivity from adjacency matrix

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have an adjacency matrix, A. I want to check if there is a path (from any vertex) which can traverse all of the vertices such that no vertex is visited again.

```
A = {{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
  0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
  1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}};
```

I solved this by constructing an `AdjancencyGraph` and then using `FindPath` for all of the vertices to check if any path exists.

```
getPathsFromNode[adjMatrix_, node_] :=
  Flatten[#, 1]&@
  (FindPath[AdjacencyGraph[adjMatrix], node, #, {8}, 1] & /@ Range[9]);
```

Now, I check if there is any path from any vertex.

```
(getPathsFromNode[A, #]!={}) & /@ Range[9] // Flatten[#, 1] &
(*{True, True, True, False, False, False, True, False, True}*)
```

This process is very slow. Is there any other way to check if a path exits without contructing an `Adjacency` graph?

Comment: Have you seen `FindHamiltonianCycle[]`?

Comment: @J.M. I tried `FindHamiltonianCycle[A // AdjacencyGraph]`, It returns empty list.

Comment: Use `FindHamiltonianPath`

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. The speed has increased by an order.

Comment: Szabolcs suggestion is probably the best method to use (for general $A$). Are there any restrictions on the graph/matrix?

Comment: @KellenMyers There are no restrictions as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path). Use [`FindHamiltonianPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindHamiltonianPath.html).